# ¿Como subir imagen en expo react native?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, react-native, expo

Estoy intentado subir una foto, subida con imagepicker, con el entorno de expo react, pero no se como enviar la imagen junto con datos:

```
const [foto, setfoto] = useState("")
 let uploadimage =(imagen,nombre_imagen)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange =()=>{
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
          resolve(xmlhttp.response)
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET",imagen)
      xmlhttp.responseType="blob"
      xmlhttp.send()
    })

  }

  let Elegirfoto = async () => {
    let permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync();
    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
      Alert.alert(
        "Alert",
        "Se requiere tene permisos para acceder a las fotos de su biblioteca!",
        { cancelable: false }
      );
      return;
    }

    let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();
    var imagen_seleccionada = pickerResult.uri
    uploadimage(imagen_seleccionada,"perfil").then(resolve=>{
      var datos_imagen = JSON.stringify(resolve)
      setfoto(datos_imagen)

    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
    })

    Alert.alert(
      "Alert",
      "Su foto se guardo correctamente!",
      [
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => setTexto("Cambiar Foto") }
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  }
```

Este es un pequeño fragmento de codigo de como obtengo la imagen, la variable datos_imagen arroja lo siguiente: {"_data":{"size":8947943,"offset":0,"blobId":"854D25A8-9EA2-4689-A5D5-6FA7762AD06F","type":"image/png","name":"E4FF361A-6F27-4B97-BC75-668B861F5370.png","__collector":{}}},

quisiera mover la imagen a una carpeta o insertar la url en una base de datos como mysql, por su parte en el fetch envio los datos, aquii esta:

```
const datos=()=>{
    fetch('http://192.160.1.24:3000/registro',{

      method:"POST",
      headers:{
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({
        nombre:nombre,
        apellido:apellido,
        correo:correo,
        fecha:fecha_input,
        password:password,
        foto:foto


      })


    })
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((res)=>{if(res.respuesta=="succes"){navigation.replace("Principal")}}
```

Esta funcion se ejecuta con un boton, que despues usando express inserta los datos en mysql-

Comment: Lo que sucede es que básicamente el content type de `application/json` no permite subir archivos. Para poder subir archivos deberías averiguar cómo hacerlo con content type de `multipart/form-data`

Comment: @GermanAlzate ya pude hacerlo :)